# How is it possible to handle large packet loss?

Tags: networking, proxy, window, packet, packet-loss

I currently live in a dorm, and the internet connection is really poor here. The speed is not bad, but around 25% of the packets are lost (randomly). The management knows the problem, but they don't really care.

Webbrowsers can mostly handle it, but FTP, skype, etc... is useless.

I would like to solve it with a software. I can connect to a linux server (which is in the university). I don't have admin rights there, but I am able to reach the internet.

The solution would be maybe to set up a proxy on the linux server, and send each package twice, or automatically resend it, if one of them is lost.

Or is it possible to manage it without using an another computer?

Comment: How can we answer when you don't tell us **where** the packet loss is occurring?

Comment: In the routers of the dorm

Comment: is it before the routers or after the routers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have correctly diagnosed the problem this is almost (but not quite) impossible to do -  you have multiple issues.

The first is tcp vs udp - Interactive traffic like Skype generally uses UDP, while web browsing and FTP use TCP.  UDP is "fire and forget", while TCP will resend.

Additionally for Skype type traffic you have to handle jitter - ie latency needs to be fairly consistent, sending multiple packets - if you can work out how to do it may still cause drops due to out of order packets and jitter issues.

That said, from your loose description, it sounds to me like the problem is more likely to be QoS/traffic classes on a router - ie making web traffic a higher priority.  (DNS is also normally UDP, so you would expect sites to randomly not load, and TCP traffic would be excruciatingly slow with significant packet less when they do load).  Also you should be aware that sometimes there are limits on the number of ICMP/some types of UDP packets to prevent DoS attacks - what you are saying may be related to this.

Before doing anything too complex, you should try and work out the exact performance characteristics.   If, as I expect, HTTP and HTTPS traffic is being prioritised, the easiest way around this might be to set up an OpenVPN tunnel over TCP on port 443 and then Skype over that.